Filter JSON Data and map it into Card
Hy guys
i have the following code for creating some calendar Card with Data from a JSON File.
import { IoLocationSharp } from "react-icons/io5";
import { FaHouse } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { IoMdMicrophone } from "react-icons/io";
import { GrAssistListening } from "react-icons/gr";
import dataConcert from "../data/concertData.json"


export const Card = ( ) => (
    <div className="cards">
        {dataConcert.map((data) => (
            <label key={data.id}>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="front">
                            <div className="information__card">
                                <div className="information__date">
                                <header>
                                    <h1>{data.day}</h1>
                                    <h2>{data.month}</h2>
                                </header>
                                </div>
                                <div className="icons__band">
                                    <h3><IoMdMicrophone /></h3>
                                    <h3><GrAssistListening /> </h3>
                                    <h3><FaHouse /></h3>
                                    <h3><IoLocationSharp /></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div className="information__band">
                                    <h3>{data.bandname}</h3>
                                    <h3>{data.Genre}</h3>
                                    <h3>{data.Location}</h3>
                                    <h3>{data.Place}</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="buttons_card">
                                <a class="fancy">
                                    <span class="top-key"></span>
                                    <span class="text">TICKETS</span>
                                    <span class="bottom-key-1"></span>
                                    <span class="bottom-key-2"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a class="fancy">
                                    <span class="top-key"></span>
                                    <span class="text">MERCH</span>
                                    <span class="bottom-key-1"></span>
                                    <span class="bottom-key-2"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </label>
        ))}
    </div>
);

Here are some examples of Data from the JSON File
{
"id":14,
"bandname":"Westernhagen",
"Genre":"Konzert - Rock",
"day":"12",
"month":"Mai.",
"year":"2024"
},
{
"id":15,
"bandname":"Acid King",
"Genre":"Konzert - Rock",
"day":"13",
"month":"Mai.",
"year":"2024"
},
{
"id":16,
"bandname":"Argies",
"Genre":"Konzert - Punkrock/Hardcore",
"day":"13",
"month":"Mai.",
"year":"2024"
},

I only want the data from the id 14 and id 15 by check the "Genre" so in this case every Data with the Genre "Konzert - Rock" should be transferred in a new Card
Is there any possibility to check if the Genre is "Konzert - Rock" and if not to skip to the next id?
I think i should do it with if and else but i don't know how to check the data in the JSON File.
Can someone help?
Greets Primo

You can filter the data based on the "Genre" field before rendering it. Here's how you can modify your Card component to achieve this:
export const Card = () => {
// Filter data based on Genre
const rockConcerts = dataConcert.filter(data => data.Genre === "Konzert - Rock");

return (
    <div className="cards">
        {rockConcerts.map((data) => (
            <label key={data.id}>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="front">
                        <div className="information__card">
                            <div className="information__date">
                                <header>
                                    <h1>{data.day}</h1>
                                    <h2>{data.month}</h2>
                                </header>
                            </div>
                            <div className="icons__band">
                                <h3><IoMdMicrophone /></h3>
                                <h3><GrAssistListening /> </h3>
                                <h3><FaHouse /></h3>
                                <h3><IoLocationSharp /></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="information__band">
                                <h3>{data.bandname}</h3>
                                <h3>{data.Genre}</h3>
                                <h3>{data.Location}</h3>
                                <h3>{data.Place}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="buttons_card">
                            <a className="fancy">
                                <span className="top-key"></span>
                                <span className="text">TICKETS</span>
                                <span className="bottom-key-1"></span>
                                <span className="bottom-key-2"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a className="fancy">
                                <span className="top-key"></span>
                                <span className="text">MERCH</span>
                                <span className="bottom-key-1"></span>
                                <span className="bottom-key-2"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
        ))}
    </div>
    );
};

If this is not what you want please let me know.

Great that's what i wanted. Is it possible to add more filters? Thank you so much @sabsab

@PrimoCenturio Yes you can filter as much as you want... it's basics javascript... you should learn and practice more JavaScript before jumping into framework like React.
